# Once add user control into reference, visual studio turns to no responding?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

I test those code independently working fine. Once I write it into user control and add it into application reference, and use it in the WPF, Visual studio turns to "Not Responding". This drives me crazy.

below is the user control code:

```
    namespace ServerUserContorl
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for UserControl1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        public Socket server;
        public Socket Command_Listening_Socket; //used to listen for connections for exchanging commands between server and mobile
        public Socket Interaction_Listening_Socket1;// designed for receiving information from mobile
        public Socket Interaction_Listening_Socket2;// designed for sending information to mobile
        public Socket Interaction_Receiving_Socket;// receiving
        public Socket Interaction_Sending_Socket;// sending


        public UserControl1()
        {

            IPAddress local = IPAddress.Parse("134.129.125.126");
            IPEndPoint iepCommand = new IPEndPoint(local, 8080);// IP end point for command listening socket
            IPEndPoint iepReceiving = new IPEndPoint(local, 8090);// IP end point for receiving socket
            IPEndPoint iepSending = new IPEndPoint(local, 9090);// Ip end point for sending socket

            //part for command listening socket connection
            server = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            server.Bind(iepCommand);
            server.Listen(20);

            // part for receiving Socket
            Interaction_Listening_Socket1 = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            Interaction_Listening_Socket1.Bind(iepReceiving);
            Interaction_Listening_Socket1.Listen(20);

            // part for sending Socket
            Interaction_Listening_Socket2 = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            Interaction_Listening_Socket2.Bind(iepSending);
            Interaction_Listening_Socket2.Listen(20);

            while (true)
            {
                // Here is three blocks for accepting the new client, 
                // once client connect to the command listening socket, 
                // pass the command listening socket to the threadService class
                // and start a thread for receiving the userID
                Command_Listening_Socket = server.Accept();
                Interaction_Receiving_Socket = Interaction_Listening_Socket1.Accept();
                Interaction_Sending_Socket = Interaction_Listening_Socket2.Accept();

                threadService service = new threadService(Command_Listening_Socket,Interaction_Receiving_Socket,Interaction_Sending_Socket);
                Thread userCommand = new Thread(service.userCommand);
                userCommand.Start();
                Debug.WriteLine("thread starts");
            }

        }
        }


}




using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

namespace ServerUserContorl
{
    class CommunicationThread
    {
        public Socket Interaction_Receiving_Socket, Interaction_Sending_Socket;

        public CommunicationThread(Socket receiving, Socket sending)
        {
            Interaction_Receiving_Socket = receiving;
            Interaction_Sending_Socket = sending;

        }
        // connect with iep2 9090, clientCom1,clientCommunication1
        public void sendThread()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("In the SendThread method");
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

            string greeting = "hello, this is the message from the server.";
            bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(greeting);
            Debug.WriteLine("the byte is " + bytes);
            int i = 0;
            while (i < 10)
            {
                Interaction_Sending_Socket.Send(bytes);
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                i++;
            }
            Debug.WriteLine("send is successful");
           // clientCommunication1.Close();
        }
        //8080
        public void receiveThread()
        {
            int i = 0;
            string data = null;
            Debug.WriteLine("In the receive method");
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

            while ((i = Interaction_Receiving_Socket.Receive(bytes)) != 0)
            {
                data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
                Debug.WriteLine("receive from the client " + data);
            }
            //clientCommunication.Close();

        }

    }
}




using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;

namespace ServerUserContorl
{
    class threadService
    {
        public Socket client;
        //public Socket clientCommunication;
        public string status;
        public Socket Interaction_Receiving_Socket, Interaction_Sending_Socket;
        public static int connections = 0;
        int i = 0;

        public threadService(Socket client,Socket receiving, Socket sending)
        {
            this.client = client;
            Interaction_Receiving_Socket = receiving;
            Interaction_Sending_Socket = sending;
        }

        public void userCommand()
        {
            string data = null;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

            if (client != null)
            {
                connections++;
            }
            Debug.WriteLine("new client connects, {0} connections", connections);
            while ((i = client.Receive(bytes)) != 0)
            {
                data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
                status = data;
                Debug.WriteLine("receive from client: " + status);

                if (status == "1")
                {
                    CommunicationThread communication = new CommunicationThread(Interaction_Receiving_Socket,Interaction_Sending_Socket);

                    Thread newSendThread = new Thread(communication.sendThread);
                    newSendThread.Start();
                    Debug.WriteLine("start the communication thread--status 1");

                    // CommunicationThread communication = new CommunicationThread();

                    Thread newReceiveThread = new Thread(communication.receiveThread);
                    newReceiveThread.Start();
                    Debug.WriteLine("start the communication thread--status 2");
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

In the WFP, I only add it:

```
xmlns:myControl="clr-namespace:ServerUserContorl;assembly=ServerUserContorl"
<myControl:UserControl1>
```

Comment: `namespace ServerUserContorl`that typo might cause some trouble if you are trying to reference it with `"clr-namespace:serverControl"`

Comment: sorry, because once I open Wpf part, will crash, I type it by hand. right now looks ok. it still not responding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio's Designer has to call the control's constructor when you add the control, which means the Designer is going into the `while(true)` loop in the constructor.

First: **Do not put an infinite loop in your control's constructor. *EVER.*** If you need something to poll endlessly, that should be handled in your program's main or, better yet, in a separate thread. Until the constructor finishes the control can't be referenced by other objects, so you *need* to let the constructor finish.

Second: If you have code in your constructor you want the *Designer* to skip, you can do this:

```
using System.ComponentModel;    

public MyControl()
{
    // code that Designer should run

    if (LicenseManager.UsageMode == LicenseUsageMode.DesignTime)
        return;

    // code that Designer should not run
}
```

Comment: It answers my question. Thanks. I run another thread for infinite loop.

Comment: But this code still said Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted

Comment: @user3779570 You should ask a new question about that.